# Ajax validation post error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
 <?php
   sleep(2);
   ob_start();

    $CategoryName = secure($_POST['cat-name']);  
    ...

    $humancheck = $_POST['humancheck'];
        $honeypot = $_POST['honeypot'];
           if ($honeypot == 'http://' && empty($humancheck)) {  
          $error_message = '';  
            if (empty($CategoryName)) 
        {
             $error_message .= "<p>Please Enter Name.</p>";            
        }   


      if (!empty($error_message)) 
        {
                    $return['error'] = true;
                    $return['msg'] = "<h3>Opps Error Here.</h3>".$error_message;                    
                    echo json_encode($return);
                    exit();
        }

        else {
                  header('Content-type: application/json');
                  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO xxx SET xx = '".$xxx."',xx = '".$xxx."',xxx = '".$xxx."',xxx = '".$xxx."'") or die(mysql_error());
                  $_SESSION['Info'] = 'Added success';

                         $return['error'] = false;
                         $return['msg'] = "<p>Wait...</p>"; 
                         echo json_encode($return);
              }

            }


?>
```

SAME PHP PAGE MY FORM

```
<form role="form" id="add" action="functions.php?type=add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat-name"id="cat-name" placeholder="name">
      ...
     <input type="hidden" name="honeypot" id="honeypot" value="http://" />            
     <input type="hidden" name="humancheck" id="humancheck" class="clear" value="" />
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading...">Add</button>
        <button type="button" onClick="parent.location='kategoriler.php'" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
      </form>
```

AJAX FUNCTION

```
function submitForm(formData) {

    $.ajax({    
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'functions.php?type=add',      
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 7000,
        success: function(data) {           
            $('#response').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'alert alert-danger' : 'alert alert-success').html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');  
        if ($('#response').hasClass('alert alert-success')) {
                        window.location.href = "kategoriler.php";
                    }

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#response').removeClass().addClass('error').html('<p>There was an<strong> ' + errorThrown +'</strong> error due to a<strong> ' + textStatus +'</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');         
        },              
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {            
            $('form')[0].reset();
        }
    }); 
};
```

Also, i have ajax validation, when i send form validation working but SubmitForm did not work. There was an

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error due to a parser error condition.
```

have this error but form values add database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

You need to mention this header in php file as you send the data in json format.

Comment: That's good practise, but not the problem. The JavaScript (`dataType: 'json',`) says to ignore the content-type header and process it as JSON regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Check that php's json_encode is doing the job correctly (posting an example of response will be of help). Tha's probably not it, but my first guess is that your JSON response is nor propertly wrapping into quotes the HTML string you send back. Something like this:

```
{
    error: false,
    msg: <p>Wait...</p>
}
```

when it should be

```
 {
    error: false,
    msg: '<p>Wait...</p>'
 }
```